# Android ImageView , image gets cut off at the top Left corner, how to avoid id?

Tags: android, image, imageview, picasso

I have an imageView with

```
scaleType="centerCrop"
```

The images are showing inside ViewPager with sliding functionality.
I am using picasso to load images, but the image gets cut off on the top left corner like below :

[image]

[image]

Here is the xml code :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_sliding"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And the code to load images is :

```
 if (imgList!=null && imgList.size()>0)
        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(imgList.get(position))
                .placeholder(drawable)
                .into(imgView);
```

So, I can't figure out why this is happening, and also the cut of part is covered sometime by blue color and sometimes by green color.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: add your whole xml code

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you've enabled `Picasso`'s debug indicators.

Try the following:

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false); // disabling the indicators

picasso
    .load(imgList.get(position))
    .placeholder(drawable)
    .into(imgView);
```

Or look for `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` in your code and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, above answers are write for the cut of adge is the reason is you are using `android:scaleType` as a center crop so its try to adjust image with your image container (ImageView) or remove extra area after fill image with image container,For resolve it you can use `android:scaleType` as  `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

And about the color is the reason of Picaso library if you are setting following property in your code then you can't get color again,

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` on your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_sliding"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```